# How can I sort a 2D vector in C++ by the first and second index?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I was wondering how in C++ I could sort a 2D vector so that it is sorted by both elements. It would be sorted in ascending order by the first element, and if there are multiple of the first element, they will be sorted by ascending order of the second element. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec = {{10, 23}, {10, 22}, {1, 100}, {13, 12}};
```

this would get sorted into:

```
{{1, 100}, {10, 22}, {10, 23}, {13, 12}}
```

Comment: Do all sub-vectors have exactly 2 elements? If not, do all sub-vectors have at least 2 elements? If not, how do you deal with sub-vectors that have 0 or 1 ints?

Comment: Just `std::ranges::sort(vec)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++20 `std::ranges::sort` would be a good option:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{10, 25}, {10, 23}, {10, 22},
                                         {10, 24}, {1, 100}, {13, 12}};
    std::ranges::sort(vec);

    for (const auto& row : vec) 
        for (const auto& col : row) 
            std::cout << col << " ";            
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/G5vovr3hh)

Output:

```
1 100 10 22 10 23 10 24 10 25 13 12
```

If not `std::sort` works just as well:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{10, 25}, {10, 22}, {10, 26},
                                         {10, 24}, {1, 100}, {13, 12}};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (const auto& row : vec)
        for (const auto& col : row) 
            std::cout << col << " ";
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/3sh3hxYMa)

Output:

```
1 100 10 22 10 24 10 25 10 26 13 12
```

Comment: @Lewis -- The trick is that `std::vector` has an overloaded `operator <`, so the `std::sort` solution works right out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b){
        return  a[0] < b[0]? true : (a[0] == b[0]) ?  a[1] < b[1] : false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
int m = vec.size();
int n = vec[0].size();
sort(vec[0].begin(), vec[0].end());


for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't meet OP's requirements. You sort first subvector, not all subvectors based on lexicographical order: https://godbolt.org/z/qvb4ez3bM

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was pretty cool when I saw it. Using a compare function to std::sort, you could write something like below. This extends quite nicely and is pretty flexible on nested orderings!

```
bool comp(vector<int> v1, vector<int> v2)
{
    if(v1[0]<v2[0])
        return true;
    else if(v1[0]==v2[0])
        return v1[1]<v2[1];
    else
        return false;
}
```